# Powershell: Optimizing script arranging high volume of files (<2MB) into folders in order

Tags: powershell, sorting, pdf, optimization, 7zip

This script is performed on 200,000+ files of about 2MB. The files need to be arranged in folders with a max count of $max. Then they will be zipped. Right now, the code below works, but can be slow. What suggestions for optimizing this script do I have? I'm not sure if regex is the way to go for sorting. Any suggestions for any optimizations are welcome. Thank you!

```
$src = "C:\srcPath"
$dst = "C:\dstPath"
Set-Alias 7z "C:\Path\7za.exe"
$max = 1000
$Container = "Files"
$ZipFileName = "Files.zip" 
$fileFilter = "*.pdf"
$fileCount = (dir $src $fileFilter| measure).Count

if ([int]$fileCount -gt 0) {
  md $dst\$Container
  $folderCount = [Math]::Ceiling([int]$fileCount / [int]$max)

  for ($n = 1; $n -le $folderCount; $n++) {
    if(!(test-path $dst\$Container\$n)){
      md $dst\$Container\$n
      Get-ChildItem -Path $src\* -File -Include $fileFilter | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name,'\d+',{ $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } | Select-Object -First $max | Copy-Item -Destination $dst\$Container\$n | Out-Null
    }
  }
  7z a $dst\$ZipFileName $dst\$Container | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Have you _measured_ anything yet? If not, start with that. If say, the `7z` call takes up 90% of the execution time then optimizing the sort ranking probably isn't worth the hassle

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought about. I'll try to figure out how I can test.

Comment: `Measure-Command` or `[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]` might help here